# 2023 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2023 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://opensource.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 6):

Due to a lack of sufficient candidates, this election was cancelled after having had its nomination period extended for a week. Given the moderation team currently has 2 moderators, and the minimum number of moderators on any Stack Exchange site is 3, the Community Management Team will be working with the moderation team and the wider community here on Meta to determine next steps — stay tuned for that.